# JSON getting "name":"\u05d7\u05d1\u05e8\u05d4" for non-English

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, json

I am getting a JSON returned by Ajax from PHP `json_encode`
I have a Hebrew characters that turned into `"\u05d7\u05d1\u05e8\u05d4"`
How can I turn them back into Hebrew?
(The DB is encoded UTF8 and when calling the PHP file the Hebrew is displayed correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Quentin pointed out, this is correct. `\uXXXX` is a correct escape sequence for a unicode character. In fact, if you type in into the firebug console, it will prompt you `"חברה"`. That does look hebrew to me, although I can't tell whether it's correct.

Therefore after parsing the data you received (either with `eval` or `JSON.parse`) the character should be unescaped automatically.

Comment: Don't use eval. It is slow, hard to debug, and risky when given untrusted data.

Answer (score 3):

You use any (non-broken) JSON parser.

Comment: can you give me an example? and on what side do I use it, JS or PHP?

Comment: The example depends on the parser you use. You use it in JS if you want to get the data in JS. You use it in PHP if you want to get the data in PHP. (Since you are encoding it in PHP, I assume you are sending it to the browser and would thus want to decode it in JS)