# mysql_real_escape_string and json

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following json string inside an associative array:

```
[watch] => '{"tv":"Dexter's Labratory, \u05d1\u05d9\u05d3\u05d5\u05e8  \u05d9\u05e9\u05e8\u05d0\u05dc\u05d9 HOT, South Park, \u05e2\u05e1\u05e4\u05d5\u05e8, Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles, Simpsons, The Samurai Pizza Cats, Dr. House, Futurama, House","movies":"Mufasa, Simba, \u05d7\u05d9\u05d9\u05dd \u05d1\u05e1\u05e8\u05d8, \u05e1\u05e8\u05d8\u05d9\u05dd \u05d7\u05d3\u05e9\u05d9\u05dd \u05d1\u05e7\u05d5\u05dc\u05e0\u05d5\u05e2, Future Shorts Israel, The Lion King"}'
```

Of course it needs to be escaped because it contains characters like ' inside (e.g Dexter's Labratory). The problem is that after using mysql_real_escape_string on it the output is:

```
[watch] => \'{\"tv\":\"Dexter\'s Labratory, \\u05d1\\u05d9\\u05d3\\u05d5\\u05e8  \\u05d9\\u05e9\\u05e8\\u05d0\\u05dc\\u05d9 HOT, South Park, \\u05e2\\u05e1\\u05e4\\u05d5\\u05e8, Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles, Simpsons, The Samurai Pizza Cats, Dr. House, Futurama, House\",\"movies\":\"Mufasa, Simba, \\u05d7\\u05d9\\u05d9\\u05dd \\u05d1\\u
```

It escapes a shitload of stuff that should not be escaped, especially all the " characters (that I am pretty sure are part of the json encoding) making it not query-able.
What's the right method to escape a json string? I guess I am missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `already prepared` JSON string.

You should use `json_encode();` function to create your JSON string from array or object.

It's automatically escapes special characters. Or you can simply define in third argument of this function what to escape. [Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) is the PHP DOCs.

Answer (score 0):

The right method to escape *any* string to put into an SQL query for MySQL is to use bound arguments. Using `mysqli_real_escape_string` trails behind and `mysql_real_escape_string` trails further behind.

Escaping characters that *can* have special meaning but don't *in context* does not cause a problem.

If you want to query the data sanely, then it shouldn't be stored in JSON format in the database. You can't access the fields in the JSON without extracting it from the database and parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the Hebrew characters you have. It needs parsing.
See this question:

[JSON getting "name":"\u05d7\u05d1\u05e8\u05d4" for non-English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676951/json-getting-name-u05d7-u05d1-u05e8-u05d4-for-non-english)